# Android Button Sizing

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I have several buttons in my application that are displayed at the bottom of the screen. Right now the buttons have text in them. When running on the emulator, the buttons with text fit nicely. Now, that I am running on the actual device, some buttons' text takes more than two lines and the screen is not very presentable. I could change the font to make it work for the device in question, but there is no guarantee that it will work on some other device. Should I create button images (with text embedded as part of the image) and then have multiple versions, depending on the size of the device screen being used? That seems like a lot of work, is there a simpler solution to this?

Thank You,
Gary

Comment: Can you post your screenshot with your layout code ?.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give equal weights to all buttons.So that all of them look similar and occupy same amount of space.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get screen resolution and set sizes as a proportion of this resolution.
Here is the sample code to obtain screen width and height.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find multiple screen size handling tutorial here:
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
your emulator may have specific resolution that is different than the one of your actual device.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard but little bit tricky. 
In this purpose you can use built in draw-able folder. In android project there are many draw-able folder like drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi where you can put different size of images and it will automatically render image based on device screen. Check this tutorial for more understanding [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Or you can take screen size dynamically. Based on the screen size you can set the button height and width.